# SQL Update query to replace last 4 characters in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, date-arithmetic

I am needing to replace the last four characters in a column.
It is currently a year in a char format and I need to replace with the current year.
The code I am using now is successful in removing the old year but is failing to input the new year that is needed.

My Current Code:

```
DECLARE @NewYear as Char
SELECT @NewYear = cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4))

UPDATE MyTable
SET ENDDATE = (substring(ENDDATE, -5, len(ENDDATE)) +@NewYear)
WHERE EndDate < StartDate
```

Original Value -  01/01/2017
Result - 01/01/
Desired Result - 01/01/2020

This is being used in SAS Proc SQl pass through - ANSI Standard SQL

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Which database provider are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, other?

Comment: SQL Server - Standard SQL - using in Proc SQL SAS

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: Are ENDDATE and STARTDATE character strings or actual dates?  If they are character strings with the year at the end instead of the beginning then the less than comparison in your WHERE clause is not going to work.  '01/01/2020' is less than '05/05/1800' .because '1' is less than '5' when comparing characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in the declaration of your variable. It should be declared as `char(4)` - otherwise it defaults to `char(1)` and ends up with value `'2'` instead of `2020`.

Also, you can use `left` instead o substring.

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @NewYear as Char(4)
SELECT @NewYear = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4))

UPDATE MyTable
SET ENDDATE = LEFT(ENDDATE , len(ENDDATE) - 4) + @NewYear
WHERE EndDate < StartDate
```

Note there is little benefit using a variable here. Very likely, the database will optimize the expression and not do the `getdate()`-based computation for each row.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ENDDATE = LEFT(ENDDATE , len(ENDDATE) - 4) + cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as char(4))
WHERE EndDate < StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET ENDDATE = STUFF(ENDDATE, 7, 4, DATENAME(year, GETDATE()))
    WHERE EndDate < StartDate;
```

The `WHERE` clause makes no sense, because you are doing date comparisons.

Note that variables are not helpful here.  You don't have to convert anything to a string, if you use `DATENAME()`, because it returns a string.

I thought for a moment they might be stored as dates, but you would never get `01/01/` as a valid date.